# Color li elements based on dynamically generated text and specific pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried some stuff for hours but hoping for help from "outside" now.

I have li elements with a `<span>` inside, that the user can rename as he wants. The name convention is always the same though and splitted with an underscore.

1. Category Name
2. Category
3. Name of element
4. Sometimes even more identifier for 3.

Example:

[image]

Since this list can become very long, I had the idea to make it more clear with random background colors. Here comes the problem.

How can I set the color for each li element based on the mentioned 1-3 syntax?
This is how it should look like:

[image]

This is what I got so far. Obviously just iterating over each li and not able to categorize it:

[image]

The code:

```js
 var lastPick;
 var rand;
 $('[tree-item-name]').each(function() {
   $(this).css('background',randomColor());
 });

 function randomColor() {
   var back = ["#ffc0cb61","rgba(192,255,210,0.38)","rgba(192,220,255,0.38)","rgba(241,192,255,0.38)","rgba(192,240,255,0.38)","rgba(255,221,192,0.38)","rgba(231,255,192,0.38)"];
   rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
   rand==lastPick?randomColor():rand;
   lastPick = rand;
   return rand;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Start</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Start_Go</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Won</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Won_Clear</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Lost</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Lost_Clear</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Quest_AskBet</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Quest_AskBet_Statistics</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Rules</span>
</li>
```

TL;DR:

The logic I want is:

1. Check all li elements and its text (of the span)
2. match groups together based on identifier
3. the first three groups split by an underscore should have the same color
4. A_B_C_123 should have the same color as A_B_C_321 but A_B_D_423 should have a different color and so on.

Hope it's clear and "simple"

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I missed that handy code injection feature  I added it at the beginning as markdown ``` code. It should now have a "Run code snippet" there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below. First get the first three groups from the `innerHTML` of each element and then check if that `key` already exists in the `items` object. If it does then take the assigned color, if not, then get a new unused random color and assign it to the newly created `key`. For the purpose of keeping track of the used colors I used an array (`picked`).

Test and run (run it a few times to see how the colors are being assigned):

```js
var picked = [];
var rand;
var items = {};

$('[tree-item-name]').each(function() {
  let groups = $(this).html().split("_");    
  if(groups.length >= 3) {
    let item = [groups[0], groups[1], groups[2]].join("_");  
    if(!items[item]) {    // if the key doesn't exist
      items[item] = {     // make a new one
        "color": randomColor()
      };
    }
    $(this).css('background', items[item].color);
  }
});

 function randomColor() {
   var back = ["#ffc0cb61","rgba(192,255,210,0.38)","rgba(192,220,255,0.38)","rgba(241,192,255,0.38)","rgba(192,240,255,0.38)","rgba(255,221,192,0.38)","rgba(231,255,192,0.38)"];
   rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
   if(picked.includes(rand)) { // if the color was already chosen before
    rand = randomColor();             // generate a new one
   } else {
    picked.push(rand);         // otherwise add the newly selected color to the tracker array
   }
   return rand;
 }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Start</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Start_Go</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Won</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Won_Clear</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Lost</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Cooldown_Lost_Clear</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Quest_AskBet</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Quest_AskBet_Statistics</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <span class="ect-tree-title" tree-item-name="BJ_Mission_Start">BJ_Mission_Rules</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
```